# Error: 302 Moved Temporarily

Tags: apache, perl, http

When I execute the code it gives the 302 Moved Temporarily Error 
If you find any mistake inthis code please let us .

```
#!C:\Perl64\bin\perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

# seraph.pl - search for Codex Seraphinianus on abebooks
use strict;
my $out_file = "result_seraph.html";    # where to save it

use LWP;
my $browser  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $browser->post('http://dogbert.abebooks.com/abe/BookSearch',
    # That's the URL that the real form submits to.
    [
        "ph"     => "2",
        "an"     => "",
        "tn"     => "Codex Seraphinianus",
        "pn"     => "",
        "sn"     => "",
        "gpnm"   => "All Book Stores",
        "cty"    => "All Countries",
        "bi"     => "Any Binding",
        "prl"    => "",
        "prh"    => "",
        "sortby" => "0",
        "ds"     => "100",
        "bu"     => "Start Search",
    ]
); 

die "Error: ", $response->status_line, "\n"
    unless $response->is_success;
open( OUT, ">$out_file" ) || die "Can't write-open $out_file: $!";
binmode(OUT);
print OUT $response->content;
close(OUT);
print "Bytes saved: ", -s $out_file, " in $out_file\n";
```

what correction I can apply on it Please let me know

Comment: What corrections have you tried to apply on it?

Answer (score 3):

From [the manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent):

> **$ua->requests_redirectable( \@requests )**
>
> This reads or sets the object's list of request names that `$ua->redirect_ok(...)` will allow redirection for. By default, this is
>   `['GET', 'HEAD']`, as per RFC 2616. To change to include 'POST',
>   consider:
>
> ```
> push @{ $ua->requests_redirectable }, 'POST';
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same code as it is from Perl & LWP book: http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch05_06.htm

Which is very old, and meanwhile the URL it refers to has moved, which is exactly what the error message says.

To solve this you'll have to allow the redirection, use the below code

```
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
push @{$browser->requests_redirectable}, 'POST';
```

Comment: It's not a pirate link. It's the author's web site. He put a version of it online when O'Reilly took it out of print.